# Assign rows according average

Tags: php, mysql

I am importing from csv. These as cases that needs to be assigned to 4 people evenly according to value of case. The values can range from $4 to $40 000 so normal count amount of cases and then assigning according to that will not work.

An example the first case can be $20 000 and the other 11 cases can be between $200 and $450 which will not make up $20 000 . So first user will get $20 000 and then the rest should be evenly spread out to the remaining 3 users.

I am stumped on how to do this in mysql or with a select from php and then writing back to mysql.

I have tried avg the amounts, summing and deviding by 4. numbering the rows and then ordering it and assigning every 4rth to a user etc. but i am not getting to this at all.

```
SELECT amount as a,'2725.5' as b
FROM `testing_assign`
ORDER BY amount DESC

#where 2725.5 is the average
```

This is what returns.

```
"a"     "b"        

"3791"  "2725.5"

"2000"  "2725.5"

"900"   "2725.5"

"890"   "2725.5"

"771"   "2725.5"

"762"   "2725.5"

"620"   "2725.5"

"456"   "2725.5"

"450"   "2725.5"

"189"   "2725.5"

"49"    "2725.5"

"24"    "2725.5"
```

expected would be

```
a           c

3791        - user 1

2000        - user 2

900         - user 3

890         - user 4

771     - user 3

762         - user 4

620         - user 3

456         - user 4

450         - user 3

189         - user 4

49          - user 2

24          - user 2

user 4 = A4+A6+A8+A10
user 3 = A3+A5+A7+A9
user 2 = A2+A11+A12
```

and user 1 gets a1 as thats the biggest and the avg sum of the ones left dont add up to that amount.

something like update case set user - user 2 where amount  =24 etc

Comment: Is your issue that you are getting "\N" instead of "user X"?

Comment: no - user /n just and example - as well as users - i need to allocate the emounts evenly accros 4 users

Answer (score 0):

I think u can sum the amount of each user when you take the value from the DB itself by using sum and grouping

```
SELECT sum(amount) as a,'2725.5' as b,`user` as c FROM `testing_assign` GROUP by `user` ORDER BY amount DESC
```

This SQL query will return the sum of each user amount just like u wanted below

```
 a       b       c
3791  2725.5  user 1 
2073  2725.5  user 2 
2741  2725.5  user 3 
2297  2725.5  user 4
```

and then you can simply use Your condition for satisfying your need.

Comment: nope - imagine there was no users, then you had to evenly distribute them accross 4 users

Comment: Can u tell more deeply? If no user then distribute to 4 user? Can u metion what u mean by 4 user?

Comment: Is there any connection between user and amount? In database? Or this amount just randomly assign to users?

Comment: just randomly assigned - no connection at all

Comment: You have 4 debt collectors and you have debit order rejections and you need to distribute the rejections evenly between these 4 users.

Answer (score 0):

Wel after digging and searching and trial and error. here is the solution to my query above.

```
    <?php
arrayBuilder();
function arrayBuilder()
{
    $list_of_items = [11, 41, 31, 15, 15, 66, 67, 34, 20, 42, 22, 25, 50,43, 22];
    rsort($list_of_items);
    $number_of_cont = 4;
    $weight_of_items = array_sum($list_of_items);
    $weight_per_cont = ($weight_of_items/$number_of_cont);
    $containers = [];
    $sumArray = $newArray = [];
    $containersSorted = buildArray($list_of_items,$number_of_cont,$containers,$weight_per_cont);
    $itemsNotAdded = itemsNotINArray($list_of_items, $containersSorted);
    foreach ($containersSorted as $k => $subArray) {
        foreach ($subArray as $id => $value) {
            if(isset($sumArray[$k])) {
                $sumArray[$k] += $value;
            }else{
                $sumArray[$k] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    sort($sumArray);
    $itemsNotAdded = array_values($itemsNotAdded);
    foreach($itemsNotAdded as $key => $value){
        foreach($sumArray as $minkey => $minval){
            if($minkey == $key) {
                $containersSorted[$key][] = $value;
                unset($itemsNotAdded[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    print_r($containersSorted);
};

function itemsNotINArray($list_of_items, $containersSorted){
    foreach($containersSorted as $conid => $conval){
        foreach($list_of_items as $key => $value){
            if(key_exists($key,$conval)){
               unset($list_of_items[$key]);
               continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return $list_of_items;
};

function getMisMatchKey($itemsNotAdded, $containersSorted){

}

function buildArray($list_of_items,$number_of_cont,$containers, $weight_per_cont){
    foreach($list_of_items as $key => $item) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_cont; $i++) {
            $total = (isset($containers[$i])) ? array_sum($containers[$i]) : 0;
            if (($total + $item) < $weight_per_cont) {
                $containers[$i][$key] = $item;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $containers;
};
```